# Why is this svg and array initiated multiple times in angular?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, d3.js

[component.ts]

```
import { Component, style } from "@angular/core";
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
import d3 = require("d3-3");
import { Data } from "../data";

@Component({
  selector: 'ts-graph',
  templateUrl: './time-seriesG.component.html',
  styles: [`
    .graph: {padding-left: 20px !important; }
  `]
})
export class timeSeriesComponent {
  sym: string[] = [];
  price: any[] = [];
  tStamp: any[] = [];
  data: any[]=[];
  arr: any;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  getData() {
    let i: number;
    this.dataService.getData()
      .subscribe(data => {
    for(i=0;i<Object.keys(data).length;i++){
      this.data.push(data[i])
    }
      });
  }

  logV() {
    this.arr = this.data.map((d,i) => ({
      //time: d.time, 
      //sym: d.sym,
      price: d.price, 
      index: i 
    }))

    this.arr = this.arr.slice(0,25)
    console.log(this.arr.slice(0,25))
  }

  lineGraph() {
    var h=400; 
    var w=350; 
    var lineFun = d3.svg.line()
                    .x(function(d){return d.index*5})
                    .y(function(d){return d.price})
                    .interpolate('linear');

    var svg = d3.select('div')
                .append('svg')
                .attr('id','LineGraph')
                .attr('width',w)
                .attr('height',h);

    var viz = svg.append('path')
                 .attr('d',lineFun(this.arr))
                 .attr('stroke','white')
                 .attr('stroke-width',2)
                 .attr('fill','none');

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();
  }

}
```

[component.html]

```
<h2>Time Series Graph</h2>
<div>{{logV()}}</div>
<div>{{lineGraph()}}</div>
```

I am trying to get a simple line graph of some data coming from a service. for some reason the svg component is created many times.

[image: Elements inspection]

Also one of my arrays seems to be initiated many times as well.

[image: Same Array twice]

I would really appreciate any suggestions, but please keep in mind that I do not have a lot of experience using angular.

The array format: 
[image]

Comment: Can you please write a console.log and print in the array values, I guess the service is returning more values and the same is added in the array and used in the d3.svg.line with index*5.

Comment: I added the photo

Comment: See there is more values in the array which gives you more lines.If you want only one line don't push all the values of the service to array instead push only one element for(i=0;i<1;i++){
      this.data.push(data[i])
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `lineGraph` from your view here `<div>{{lineGraph()}}</div>`. So everytime a changedetection is triggered, the function is called, resulting in many, many, many appended svgs.

Just call it once in after the data is received and you should only get one svg.